# Having trouble reading gps NEMA sentences using pi pico

Tags: gps, raspberry-pi-pico

Hi first time using forum so sorry if I did something wrong.
I'm trying to make a simple gps NMEA sentence reader using a raspberry pi pico and a gps module I have hooked up to it. Here is the code I created.

```
from machine import Pin, UART

gps_module = UART(1, baudrate=9600, tx=Pin(4), rx=Pin(5))

while(1):
    NMEA = gps_module.readline()
    print(NMEA)
```

My problem is all that's outputted is "None". I am new to programming so all knowledge is helpful. If anyone knows how to get it to output the NEMA sentences from the gps module please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Note: we have a sister site about raspberry pi: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ It may be more relevant: I suspect the problem is in hardware initialization or protocol.